# Avoid dropdown submenu element to close main dropdown when clicked

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm making a regular dropdown menu with submenus for some options, everything works fine but the only problem is that because the interaction is based on the parent LI element that contains the submenu every time I click inside a submenu element the drop-down will also close.

Here's my HTML:

```
  <aside class="layout-sidebar">
    <nav class="mainSidebar navbar navbar-expand-lg" role="navigation">                              
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="js-MainNavigation">               
        <ul class="navPrimary">
          <li class="is-active">
            <a href="#" class="home">Inici</a>
          </li>
          <li class="dropdownItem">
            <a href="#" class="imi">L'IMI</a>
            <div class="subMenu">
              <div class="subMenu__content">
                <ul class="subMenu__content-list">
                  <li><a href="#">Ets Nou A L'IMI</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Coneix L'IMI</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Persones I Funcions</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Organigrama</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Direccions</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Proveidors</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Directori De Sales</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Espais Fisics</a></li>
                </ul>
              </div>
            </div> 
          </li>
          <li class="dropdownItem">
            <a href="#" class="news">Actualitat</a>
            <div class="subMenu">
              <div class="subMenu__content">
                <ul class="subMenu__content-list">
                  <li>
                    <a href="#">Llistat De Comunicats</a>
                  </li>
                  <li>
                    <a href="#">Noticies Del Sector</a>
                  </li>
                  <li>
                    <a href="#">Dossier De Premsa</a>
                  </li>
                  <li>
                    <a href="#">Calendari D'Esdeveniments</a>
                  </li>
                </ul>
              </div>               
            </div>
          </li>
          <li class="dropdownItem">
            <a href="#" class="documentation">Documentació</a>
            <div class="subMenu">
              <div class="subMenu__content">
                <ul class="subMenu__content-list">
                  <li>
                    <a href="#">Llistat De Documents</a>
                  </li>
                  <li>
                    <a href="#">Wiki</a>
                  </li>
                </ul>
              </div>               
            </div>                    
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#" class="serviceCatalog">Catàleg de serveis</a>
          </li>
          <li class="dropdownItem">
            <a href="#" class="projects">Projectes</a>
            <div class="subMenu">
              <div class="subMenu__content">
                  <ul class="subMenu__content-list">
                    <li>
                      <a href="#">Llistat De Comunicats</a>
                    </li>
                  </ul>
              </div>               
            </div>                    
          </li>
          <li class="dropdownItem">
            <a href="#" class="privateSpace">El meu espai</a>
            <div class="subMenu">
              <div class="subMenu__content">
                <ul class="subMenu__content-list">
                  <li>
                    <a href="#">Les Meves Dades</a>
                  </li>
                  <li>
                    <a href="#">Els Meus Espais De Col·laboració</a>
                  </li>
                  <li>
                    <a href="#">Les Meves Incidències</a>
                  </li>
                  <li>
                    <a href="#">Calendari D'Esdeveniments</a>
                  </li>
                  <li>
                    <a href="#">Enllaços a RRHH</a>
                  </li>
                </ul>
              </div>               
            </div>                    
          </li>
        </ul>  
        <ul class="navSecondary">
            <li><a href="#">Peticions i incidències</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Preguntes freqüents</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Espais de col·laboració</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Tens un suggeriment?</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Mapa web</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>  
    </nav>
  </aside>
```

Here's My SCSS (Basically just the part that will show and hide the submenu depending if there's a "current" class or not on the parent "LI" tag:

```
li {    
&.dropdownItem {
      &.current {
        background: url("../images/icon-close-submenu.png") 92% 25px no-repeat;
        padding-bottom: 0;
        .subMenu {
          height: 100%;
          &__content {
            -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
            transform: translateY(0);
          }
        }
      }
    }
}
```

And here's the JS that will toggle the class current in order for the submenu to show:

```
$(".navPrimary .dropdownItem").click(function(e) {
  $(".navPrimary .dropdownItem")
    .not($(this))
    .removeClass("current");
  $(this).toggleClass("current");
  return false;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The trick was to use $(e.target) to check if the parent "LI" was clicked:

```
$(".navPrimary .dropdownItem").click(function(e) {
  var target = $(e.target);
  if (target.is(".dropdownItem") || target.is(".dropdownItem > a")) {
    $(".navPrimary .dropdownItem")
      .not($(this))
      .removeClass("current");
    $(this).toggleClass("current");
    return false;
  }
});
```